# type guard function doesn't work. type still be judged as string

Tags: typescript

I'm confused why sometimes my type guard function doesn't work.

For instance, I have type guard functions below.

```
enum Services {
  email = 'Email',
  cloud = 'Cloud',
  map = 'Map',
}


// this is ok.
const isValidService = (value: string): value is keyof typeof Services => {
  return value in Services;
}

// this doesn't work. 
const isKeyOfEnum = <T>(enumObject: T) => (value: string): value is keyof typeof T => value in enumObject;
```

and used them in code below

```
const handleServicesChange = useCallback((item: string) => {

    if (isValidService(item)) {
      // type of item is judged as 'email' | 'cloud' | 'map'
      console.log(Services[item]);
    }
  }, []);
```

```
const handleServicesChange = useCallback((item: string) => {
    const isServiceKey = isKeyOfEnum(Services);

    if (isServiceKey(item)) {
      // type of item still be judged as string ...
      console.log(Services[item]);
    }
  }, []);
```

So why isKeyOfEnum can't work? And how to refactor it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on here:

```js
// Original code
const isKeyOfEnum = <T>(enumObject: T) =>
  (value: string): value is keyof typeof T => value in enumObject;
```

Firstly – `T` is a type so TS reports that `typeof T` is trying to use a type as a value. Just use `T`, not `typeof T`.

TS then reports that `Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string'`. Your input is always `string` but the asserted return type actually weakens this to `string | number | symbol`. Fine, just narrow the asserted type to `Extract<keyof T, string>`.

Finally, `value in enumObject` shows an error: `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'object'. This type parameter might need an` extends object `constraint.` Great, just add the suggested type constraint on `T`.

Putting it all together you get:

```js
const isKeyOfEnum = <T extends object>(enumObject: T) =>
  (value: string): value is Extract<keyof T, string> => value in enumObject;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAysBOA3AlgY2AZygbwFBSmAgENkAbKAXigHIBRE8mgGnylTIHswATK2gMJdeLNiQAO-GgFli40QF9cuVJxAYALlGQYA0sACeAeQBmdcNGoAeACqEAHhtA8snAEYArYKg0A+ABSgkEae3hoAXFA2AJRUvmz+iMRkYMCRmvDIIADm0ZFJKcDaWHSO8MQ+VgDWhpwmUcxQGVnZvnFQBanaIIQWIV4+ANzKqupaABbEIDxkwHBIaJgCkzlF1P7+yE4Q6RqZObGUbXgEo5rF8yjo+gb8Ojem5pD+l4sY0cNsyPWbGK-Xhk222isROBCgAHoIVANAZxEU6tptsUoCBOAB3KAAIiIpDIWKgAB9sRxuDwCcSsRIsWxTmoMJxZgA6LjZF4IK6YADaWyIAF0PmwlAoPkA)